# Add a custom button to titlebar in Windows Mobile 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way to add a button to the title bar in windows mobile 5?  (Next to the X or OK button.)

I have an app that locks the users out of the start button, so I need to create an alternate way of launching the help file.

Failing the title bar, I will look for a way to customize what a hardware button does.

I am using C#.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.  That bar (which is actually a separate app) is extensible only by the OEM.